# Spectrum of a ring: contraction of prime ideals, preimage and quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $\psi:R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $\text{Spec}(\psi):\text{Spec}(S)\rightarrow\text{Spec}(R),\mathfrak{p}\mapsto\psi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $S$. In fact, $\psi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ contains $\text{ker}(\psi)$. Why can we say that $\psi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ can be considered as an ideal of $R/\text{ker}(\psi)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addition to Alberto, maybe redundant: consequence of the bijection of sets:
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, $I$ any proper ideal. Then $$ \{\mathbf{p} \in \textbf{Spec}(A): I \subset\mathbf{p}\} \leftrightarrow \mathbf{Spec}(A/I)$$

Answer (score 1):

For any ring $R$, $I \leq R $, ideals in $ R/I$ are exactly the image at the quotient of ideals $J$ of the form $I \subset J \subset R $.
So it is just the definition, together with the fact that both $ker(\psi) $ and $ \psi^{-1}(\psi)$ are ideals (which can be easily proved).